# Active class dynamic in bootstrap tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I cant seem to get the active class to change to the corresponding item selected (see code bellow)

So I would like the active class to change depending on the `thumbnail` selected.

**html**

```
 <h2 class="">title</h2>

   <div class="row text-center advice-bar" id="myTab">
        <div class="col-md-3 overlord-thumbnail">
            <div class="thumbnail thumbnail-yellow active">
                <a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">
                    <img src="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/antenna.svg">
                </a>
            </div>
                <h3>one</h3>

                <p>text</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3 overlord-thumbnail">
            <div class=" thumbnail thumbnail-blue">
                <a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">
                    <img src="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/bar-chart.svg">
                </a>
            </div>
                <h3>two</h3>

                <p>Text</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3 overlord-thumbnail">
            <div class=" thumbnail thumbnail-red">
                <a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">
                    <img src="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/app.svg">
                </a>
            </div>
                <h3>Three</h3>

                <p>Text</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3 overlord-thumbnail">
            <div class=" thumbnail thumbnail-green">
                <a href="#tab4" data-toggle="tab">
                    <img src="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/speech-bubbles.svg">
                </a>
            </div>
                <h3>Foure</h3>

                <p>text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#myTab a').click(function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.parent().siblings().removeClass('active').end().addClass('active');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Where is your `myTab` element in your markup?

Comment: @nashcheez He mean to say `#tab1 #tab2 #tab3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the following `jQuery` code:

```
 $('#myTab a').click(function(e) {
    $($('#myTab a').parent()).addClass("active").not(this.parentNode).removeClass("active");   
    e.preventDefault();
 });
```

jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/nashcheez/m1mbp9ke/

Comment: sorry active class still static not dynamic

Comment: no, first one stays acive the new one i click dose not turn active

Comment: @BenjaminOats There was an issue with the `this` reference. Now it should work for sure! :)

Comment: Hmm still not working, ill investigate what going on

Comment: I think there is something strange on my page, ill fix this first

Comment: @BenjaminOats I made a fiddle for you, seems to be working fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/nashcheez/m1mbp9ke/

Comment: worked perfect, was my fault my jquery was not referenced correctly +1 for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `active` class first using `$('.active').removeClass('active');` and change the `addClass()` to be added like this `$this.parent().addClass('active');` (this will add the active class to the parent of the current clicked element, in this case the element with `thumbnail` class). Try this:

```js
$('#myTab  a').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $this = $(this);
  $('.active').removeClass('active');
  $this.parent().addClass('active');
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 100px;
}
.active {
  border: 1px solid #F00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 class="">title</h2>

<div class="row text-center advice-bar" id="myTab">
  <div class="col-md-3 overlord-thumbnail">
    <div class="thumbnail thumbnail-yellow active">
      <a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">
                    <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/1562/italian-landscape-mountains-nature.jpg">
                </a>
    </div>
    <h3>one</h3>

    <p>text</p>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-3 overlord-thumbnail">
    <div class=" thumbnail thumbnail-blue">
      <a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">
                    <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/1562/italian-landscape-mountains-nature.jpg">
                </a>
    </div>
    <h3>two</h3>

    <p>Text</p>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-3 overlord-thumbnail">
    <div class=" thumbnail thumbnail-red">
      <a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">
                    <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/1562/italian-landscape-mountains-nature.jpg">
                </a>
    </div>
    <h3>Three</h3>

    <p>Text</p>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-3 overlord-thumbnail">
    <div class=" thumbnail thumbnail-green">
      <a href="#tab4" data-toggle="tab">
                    <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/1562/italian-landscape-mountains-nature.jpg">
                </a>
    </div>
    <h3>Foure</h3>

    <p>text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is strange, other tabs activate on my page but the images are still not changing state

Comment: @BenjaminOats, there is nothing strange. Have you runned the snippet to see it in action. The code works. The active class is added on the element with `thumbnail` class each time you click on the image, and `active` class is removed from the previous active element.

Comment: yes, I agree your code works. im saying on my page i have other tabs that are running with your code but not the tabs i am trying to run. I am saying somthing stage is up on my page i need to fix first